# EditText is hidden on Samsung Galaxy

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i have the following layout

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/displaysms_listView1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"                        
            android:layout_height="319dp" />    
        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/displaysms_textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Write Message"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/displaysms_relativeLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/displaysms_btn_send"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"                    
                android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:text="Send"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/displaysms_btn_clear"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:gravity="fill_vertical"
                android:text="Clear"
                android:textSize="12sp" />
      </RelativeLayout>    
</LinearLayout>
```

i have done `adjustPan` in the manifest file and it works fine on devices except samsung galaxy the `EditText` hides under the soft keyboard, any suggestions, i just want a `EditText` and buttons at the bottom of my list view

my `Activity` looks like

```
<activity
            android:name="com.SMSActivity"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan|adjustResize"
```

Comment: your listview height is always fixed, which is not a good idea.. when u r using the app on small screens.. ur listview might cover the  whole screen

Comment: @contactmeandroid I understood your above comment. What will be the proper way to assign dimensions to view

Comment: tnx for the quick responses ill try the suggestions and get back

Comment: @contactmeandroid already upvoted the ans

Comment: @kaushik edited the OP, that is irrelevant to the question so didnt included it in the OP

Comment: have u tried my answer @dakait

Comment: @kaushik ill try it on the device in a while and give you the feedback

Comment: @dakait if u have any problem with this layout let me know :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

u can do something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="100" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/displaysms_listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="20" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="80"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/displaysms_textView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:hint="Write Message"
            android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />

        <FrameLayout
           android:id="@+id/FrameLayout1"
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/displaysms_btn_send"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="left|center_vertical"
               android:padding="5dp"
               android:text="Send"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />

           <Button
               android:id="@+id/displaysms_btn_clear"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_gravity="right|center_vertical"
               android:padding="5dp"
               android:text="Clear"
               android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium" />
      </FrameLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

in ur manifest file

```
<activity
    android:name="com.SMSActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize" />
```

[**Take a look for ref**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2150078/how-to-check-visibility-of-software-keyboard-in-android/4737265#4737265)

Comment: just one more thing the buttons are appearing too small the text is cutting off...

Comment: if u have only 2 button u can use **FrameLayout** instead of **RelativeLayout** give little padding for both button i hav updated my answer

Answer (score 3):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/displaysms_relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/displaysms_listView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="319dp"
        android:layout_margin="5dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/displaysms_textView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/displaysms_listView1"
        android:layout_margin="5dp"
        android:hint="Write Message"
        android:inputType="textVisiblePassword" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/displaysms_relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/displaysms_relativeLayout1" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/displaysms_btn_send"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:text="Send"
        android:textSize="12sp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/displaysms_btn_clear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:text="Clear"
        android:textSize="12sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it works on samsung devices except the galaxy duos :(

Answer (score 1):

try doing editText.requestFocus()